# Import completed data from one template to another

Tags: microsoft-word, import, templates

I have a word template with several drop down and text box fields fields thru out.  Once the user completes it for a client they save it.  When that client comes up again in the future this template has to be completed again.  Most of the time the drop down responses are the same.  Instead of rekeying the answers what is the best way to copy the contents from the last template and import them into the new template so that they only have to modify the drop downs or text fields that have changed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask. Note that this is not going to be easy. Word is not a database program.his will not be easy